# JDBC Pagination: vendor specific sql versus result set fetchSize

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, pagination

There are a lot of different tutorials across the internet about pagination with JDBC/iterating over huge result set. 
So, basically there are a number of approaches I've found so far:

1. [Vendor specific sql](http://java.avdiel.com/Tutorials/JDBCPaging.html)
2. Scrollable result set (?)
3. Holding plain result set in a memory and map the rows only when necessary (using fetchSize)

   > The result set fetch size, either set explicitly, or by default equal
   >   to the statement fetch size that was passed to it, determines the
   >   number of rows that are retrieved in any subsequent trips to the
   >   database for that result set. This includes any trips that are still
   >   required to complete the original query, as well as any refetching of
   >   data into the result set. Data can be refetched, either explicitly or
   >   implicitly, to update a scroll-sensitive or
   >   scroll-insensitive/updatable result set.
4. Cursor (?)
5. [Custom seek method paging implemented by jooq](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/26/faster-sql-paging-with-jooq-using-the-seek-method/)

Sorry for messing all these but I need someone to clear that out for me.
I have a simple task where service consumer asks for results with a pageNumber and pageSize. Looks like I have two options:

1. Use vendor specific sql
2. Hold the connection/statement/result set in the memory and rely on jdbc fetchSize

In the latter case I use [rxJava-jdbc](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-jdbc) and if you look at [producer implementation](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/davidmoten/rx/jdbc/QuerySelectProducer.java) it holds the result set, then all you do is calling request(long n) and another n rows are processed. Of course everything is hidden under Observable suggar of rxJava. What I don't like about this approach is that you have to hold the resultSet between different service calls and have to clear that resultSet if client forgets to exhaust or close it. (Note: resultSet here is java ResultSet class, not the actual data)

So, what is recommended way of doing pagination? Is vendor specific sql considered slow compared to holding the connection?

I am using oracle, ScrollableResultSet is not recommended to be used with huge result sets as it caches the whole result set data on the client side. [proof](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#sthref620)

Answer (score 1):

Keeping resources open for an indefinite time is a bad thing in general. The database will, for example, create a cursor for you to obtain the fetched rows. That cursor and other resources will be kept open until you close the result set. The more queries you do in parallel the more resources will be occupied and at some point the database will reject further requests due to an exhausted resource pool (e.g. there is a limited number of cursors, that can be opened at a time).

Hibernate, for example, uses vendor specific SQL to fetch a "page" and I would do it just like that.

Comment: Thanks, haven't thought about limited number of cursors. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches because there are many different use cases.

Do you actually expect users to fetch every page of the result set?  Or are they more likely to fetch the first page or two and try something else if the data they're interested in isn't there.  If you are Google, for example, you can be pretty confident that people will look at results from the first page, a small number will look at results from the second page, and a tiny fraction of results will come from the third page.  It makes perfect sense in that case to use vendor-specific code to request a page of data and only run that for the next page when the user asks for it.  If you expect the user to fetch the last page of the result, on the other hand, running a separate query for each page is going to be more expensive than running a single query and doing multiple fetches.

How long do users need to keep the queries open?  How many concurrent users?  If you're building an internal application that dozens of users will have access to and you expect users to keep cursors open for a few minutes, that might be reasonable.  If you are trying to build an application that will have thousands of users that will be paging through a result over a span of hours, keeping resources allocated is a bad idea.  If your users are really machines that are going to fetch data and process it in a loop as quickly as possible, a single `ResultSet` with multiple fetches makes far more sense.

How important is it that no row is missed/ every row is seen exactly once/ the results across pages are consistent?  Multiple fetches from a single cursor guarantees that every row in the result is seen exactly once.  Separate paginated queries might not-- new data could have been added or removed between queries being executed, your sort might not be fully deterministic, etc.

Comment: There will be two usecases: 1. Another service will call an app and fetch all the data for each request(hundreds of them - sequentially) (requests produce completely different huge result sets). 2. Other client applications will likely fetch only 1,2..5 pages but they will most likely do it concurrently (hundreds of requests, not thousands). Re: it's better to not miss the row, but rows are updated once per 15 minutes, so during that time results will be consistent anyway.

Answer (score 1):

ScrollableResultSet caches result on client side - this requires memory resources. But for example PostgreSQL does it by default and nobody complains. Some databases simply use client's memory to hold the **whole** resultset. In most cases the database has to process much more data to re-evaluate the query.
Also you usually have much more clients, than database instances.

Also note that query re-execution - using rownum - as implemented by Hibernate does not guarantee correct(consistent) results. If data are modified between executions and default isolation level is used.

It really depends on use case. Changing Oracle's init parameter for max. connections and also for open cursors requires database restart. 
So ScrollableResultSet and cursors can be used only when you can predict amount of (concurrent) users.

Comment: Consistency can be guaranteed passing WHERE update_ts < max_upd_ts_from_last_rs. Acceptable for me. Also am I right that the only benefit of scrollable result set is using the method #absolute(int row)?

Comment: You also have to handle deleted records. Or you have to use only "logical" delete - just mark records as deleted. Also you might need to see records as they were at 1st execution. The problem with consistency is complex and usually is not worth of trying. Re-execution might have significant performance impact, when using more complex joins. Usually you might want the execution plan of the query to be changed for each page. First pages can be returned easier then last pages. For Oracle it is much easier to "slurp" the result once using a single exec. plan.

Comment: Thanks for a valuable comment. Indeed I missed the delete case and missed that once I updated the old record it will shift the second page one element down even if I have that WHERE clause.